# Forward Engineer not creating tables from Model in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-workbench, database-schema, forward-engineer

I am completely confused by the way Workbench works. Here are the steps I take, but I don't know where my mistake is.

1. I created a localhost connection.
2. Created a Model.
3. Created a database in the local connection.
4. Forward Engineered the Model into the local connection.
5. Tables from the Model are not in the database???

Can someone help me with this dark magic? I am a beginner and the process is very confusing.

Comment: how you did step 4?

Comment: @SiddharthKumar [I did it like this](http://imgur.com/a/BCW1N)

Comment: @SiddharthKumar I figured it out. It was created all along, but under a different name. I gave the model another name, and looked for another in the databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

My mistake was that I forgot to give the model a name, and the forward engineering created it with a default one.

Also, I tried creating the database manually (with one name) which is redundant since the database was created already (with another).

The steps would be:

1. Create a localhost connection.
2. Create a Model **AND name it**.
3. Forward Engineer the Model into the local connection.